# Glass boxes and Hadlaka Oseh Mitzvah

Tags: halacha, chanuka, weather, menora-chanukia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fish Tank Menorahs](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4457/fish-tank-menorahs)

I think this is a familiar question, but since I don't have an answer, I'll ask it here.
 Since the halacha is that [Hadlaka Oseh Mitzva](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49628&st=&pgnum=284) (the conditions at the time of lighting need to be adequate), how can one put a menora (chanukiah) in a glass box outdoors to protect it from blowing out? At the actual time of lighting, i.e. before the box was closed, the candles were not in a position to last the required half hour b/c of the wind. Only once you close the glass will they be OK - but Hadlaka Oseh Mitzva so it should be too late.
I was told that many achronim deal with this question. I would be happy if someone could bring links to sources or atleast sumamrise the various opinions.